# Psychological Effects of being the World's only supernatural creature

Tags: psychology, supernatural

Here's the pitch: A character gets outed as a supernatural creature. This person grew up around normal humans, grew up into adulthood (without anyone finding out what they are), and even has normal human siblings and parents. They only found out their otherness around puberty (what can I say, I love that trope). They have a human lifespan, and whatever can kill a human will most likely kill them as well.The character had a few interviews, assured the public that they meant no harm, and participated in some minimally invasive experiments. It has been days, then weeks, then months, and eventually a year, yet no-other supernatural creature has made its presence known.

My question is: How would this effect someone mentally if they were that supernatural creature?

Comment: Was the Char actually raised by humans? Did he know he was not human at the time? If he simply existed, how did he know to learn the language and interact with humans outside of a family environment? How do humans react to him? Is he treated as a rockstar or a pariah? There's a lot of context needed here to flesh out. We're even assuming at this point a conventional human psychology, and that might not be useful. Humans are social creatures but not all animals are and then if your char has the supernatural equivalent of Asperger's Syndrome, you'll get a different effect again...

Comment: This question is 100% POB since it's impossible to guess how or what that person's mental state is. "Normal" is very subjective as well, what is normal to one person may not be to another. If you suddenly found out you were a supernatural creature, and I also did, I ***guarantee*** we would have different mental states and thoughts. VTCing

Comment: Supernatural in what way ?  As described the character is simply human and there's no apparent difference between them and humans.

Comment: I think your character passes the duck test: it grows like a human, behaves like a human, can be killed like a human... it is safe to assume it is human.

Comment: You really have to tell us whats different with this human

Comment: "They" is not "A character".  Honestly, even in 2018, you're allowed to specify gender, even if it's a guy.

Answer (score 2):

I think the psychological effect of actually having the power would be much more significant than the psychological effect of being a mutant, so the character change would be dependent to a large degree on what power they have and what they choose to do with it.  However, in any case they would end up being at least a minor celebrity and having exaggerated stories of their powers become regular features in tabloids.

It sounds like they don't undergo major life changes so they might end up just feeling kind of alienated by way of everyone in their small town ceasing to think of them other than in respect to their superpower—feeling like they're not really a person any more.  Maybe they start hanging out with a crew of weirdoes that also don't feel like they belong there.  Or maybe they get sick of the gossip and move to New York or LA where they can blend in more.

Answer (score 0):

### DEPENDS

There are many scenarios you can play here, I'll just give you two, then you decide.

(This scenarios depict that your "Character" has everything **SUPER** e.g strength, speed, stamina, intelligence, etc..)

1) He might become a **Super weapon for HIR**E - Imagine having someone fighting of enemies for your sake, while paying him less money than what you would pay for a whole army (Including all that ammo, vehicles, personnel, etc..)?

He might also be the key to world peace, as he might have the ability to destroy any technologies or countries (Or Religion) that encourages/instigates/promotes war. It actually depends on him, what he want to stand up against, weather it is **WAR** or **PEACE**, if he chooses a side, the opposing side might have a great disadvantages ahead of them.

---

In this scenario, the character might feel powerful, where every nation will bow down his knees, follow his every commands and get paid for something he can do very easily. He can become a Tyrant if he wishes.

---

2) He will be **Hunted**. As an Individual, you may chose a side and then win for that side right? Why not make someone like you to even the odds? Better yet, **Why not make an army out of you**? Nations from all over earth will hunt down your DNA, weather its your hair, blood, skin, any of it can make a difference when replicating you one way or another, if a country accomplishes on killing you or paralyzing you to be experimented on, then they can create copies of you more quickly, so your character might be always on the move, always ready to fight.

---

In this scenario, fear and anxiety will be ever present, as the whole world will want something like you for their own benefit.

---

There are a lot of things that can happen to someone that is very extra ordinary, if its something we talk about in a "**SUPER**" way, he might be better of not telling it to anyone.

Comment: I feel this answer might be a little out of scope, since it doesn't address the psychological effects on the hero, but rather talks about possible plot developments.

Answer (score 0):

There are only two outcomes: He became serial killer/dictator killer/killer in general. For more info about please read *"Also speak Zaratustra"* by **Nietzsche**. He is ubermensch. If he realize that and became man of his own he will remove himself from puny human laws and rules. For good or bad cause, depending on his teen angst.

The second option is he become Brian Jones, Jimi Hendrix et consortes. A godlike persona far better than mere mortal doing task no human could dream about. And with knowledge of that fact will come either gigantic emptiness that he may try to fill with alcohol, drugs, sex and coloring books for adults.

OR and this is option best for rest of humanity he will have a great humbleness in him and realize that he may be supernatural in some aspects there are humans who are better than him in others. Like Dalai Lama for example, Doctors without Borders etc. Then the may think on how to use his powers for good
**BUT**
He may get disappointed in humanity and try to do: *Ozymandias* from Watchmen, that villain from Bond movie who wanted to kill all humans, became a global threat like *Superman* in Injustice.